# How to avoid recurring code-bugs as an integrator based on the symptoms?

Tags: c++, c, bug-tracking

When integrating submodule-releases into parent projects I regularly encounter bugs which are only visible and triggered when integrated. This is normal. Bugs are normal. We debug them, fix them and submit them into the submodule.

Now it happened several times that such fixes are overwritten by a submodule-developer later on and reoccur in the project which integrated this submodule.

Over time and due to virtually no intelligent tracking of their behavior and their symptoms it happens that it was forgotten and it is fixed again. This is extremely time-consuming especially if it is tricky one.

Hence my question: how can I technically store the 'behavior' of a bug to be "reminded" when I see its symptoms again?

Is there a tool which addresses my problem. Anything I can used to categorize fixed bugs by symptoms?

One idea I had was to extend a static-analyser (such as coverity or clang-analyzer) with custom-patterns. This would not address the behavior/symptoms-approach but I could analyze the code during compilation with patterns created during the first fixing: "if this code is written in a certain way it is not good". In my experience I could address quite an amount of bugs this way, but not all of them.

I added C and C++ tags as these are the languages I'm using.

**UPDATE**: As there were questions in the comments: We are using git. and the bugs which are re-appearing are committed months or even years after their first correction.

**UPDATE**: we are using Mantis for bug-tracking.

Comment: If you are using a version control system e.g git with a policy were developers are responsible to use latest snapshot, then possibly this can be avoided easily. This doesn't solve your issue entirely though. Between git commits can have corresponding bug numbers mapped as well.

Comment: Adding unit tests with a reference to the bug, when it is fixed.

Comment: Which source control system are you using and do developers know how to use it?  The implication of what you say is that you are integrating sub-modules that are derived from out-of-date sources.  After you have integrated a sub-module and fixed its bugs, your developers should not be able to check-in any new changes based upon older versions of that sub-module.

Comment: @OlafDietsche The project is a firmware for a complex hardware. Due to certain constraints I'm very limited with unit-testing. IOW: you're right some of the bugs I can find like that (and we do already), but some of them I only observe by their behavior when running the full-system.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tool, but rather a process. I have used BFV (Bug Fix Verification) tests to do this. Everytime you fix a bug, you add an automated BFV test for it. The name of the test would be BFV#bugno - this is the bug number in the bug database. As part of all builds which are given to testing, run all BFV tests as part of regression testing. If BFV2042 fails, you can look up Bug#2042 in your bug database to be reminded about it. If you are running regression tests before accepting merges from submodule branches, then it's even better.